# Techprocess Payment Gateway Wordpress Plugin

Tags: wordpress, payment-gateway

Hi Guys i have TechProcess payment Gateway PHP file please any one help me in creating into wordpress plugin or create plugin for me i ready to pay for me

Comment: [We are not your personal research assistants or employees.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553) Questions are supposed to address a specific issue, not be a tutorial. Please do some research first, and then if you have *specific questions* feel free to ask them here.

Answer (score 0):

I know one vendor from India who can help you on this, 
http://fifthdimensiontech.com
They have done integrations for bots techprocess and ccavenue on worpress & woocommerce. You can find the contact info on their website. Hope it helps :)

Comment: hey can any of you help me with techprocess gateway and woo commerce?

Comment: sure @bluepicaso you can write to us on info[AT]fifthdimensiontech.com, we will do it.

Comment: my client called you, you are asking too much money, he says.
i know developer dont help much personally, but let me know how can u help?